# Haskell Type Destructuring in Guards

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, pattern-matching

I'm playing around with a toy project in Haskell. I'm implementing some data structures I've built in other languages before to familiarize myself with how they'd be built in Haskell. This isn't my first functional language, I've built a couple of projects like a Scheme interpreter in OCaml but I think my OCaml experience is coloring how I'm approaching this problem. Its' not terribly important, but may be useful for context, to know that the data structure I'm implementing is a PR-Quadtree.

What I want to do is match and destructure a type inside a guard, a la OCaml's match statement.

```
data Waypoint = WayPoint {
    lat :: Float,
    lon :: Float,
    radius :: Float,
    speed :: Float,
    accel :: Float
} deriving (Show)

data Region = Region {
    x :: Float,
    y :: Float,
    width :: Float
} deriving (Show)

data PRQuadtree = WhiteNode Region
    | BlackNode Region Waypoint 
    | GreyNode { 
        topLeft :: PRQuadtree,
        topRight :: PRQuadtree,
        botLeft :: PRQuadtree,
        botRight :: PRQuadtree,
        region :: Region
    } deriving (Show)

getRegion node 
    | BlackNode(r, _) = r
    | WhiteNode(r) = r
    | GreyNode = region node
```

The `getRegion` function is the one I am having problems with in particular. In case what I'm trying to do is unclear: I'd like to simple extract one element of the argument but that depends on which member of the algebraic data type the argument is. In OCaml I could do:

```
let getRegion node = match node with
    | BlackNode(r, _) = r
    | WhiteNode(r) = r
    | GreyNode = region(node)
```

(or something very similar, my OCaml is a bit rusty now).

In Haskell however, this doesn't appear to bind `r` in scope of the RHS of the guard branch. I've tried to look up Pattern Guards, as they sound similar to what I might want to do, but I can't really grok whats going on here. Really I just want to get a binding from the LHS of the = to the RHS of the equals (depending on which branch of the guard we've gone down).

Whats the idiomatic Haskell way to do what I'm trying to do here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It can be achieved as follows:

```
getRegion :: PRQuadtree -> Region
getRegion (BlackNode r _) = r
getRegion (WhiteNode r) = r
getRegion GreyNode{region=r} = r
```

or even as

```
getRegion :: PRQuadtree -> Region
getRegion x = case x of
  BlackNode r _ -> r
  WhiteNode r -> r
  GreyNode{} -> region x
```

In Haskell, prepending a type signature is very idiomatic.

Another option is extending the `region` field to the other cases as well:

```
data PRQuadtree = WhiteNode { region :: Region }
    | BlackNode { region :: Region , waypoint :: Waypoint }
    | GreyNode { 
        topLeft :: PRQuadtree,
        topRight :: PRQuadtree,
        botLeft :: PRQuadtree,
        botRight :: PRQuadtree,
        region :: Region
    } deriving (Show)
```

Now, `region` will work on all `PRQuadtree` values.

Haskell uses `|` as ML does when defining algebraic datatypes, to separate different constructors, but does not use it to separate `case` branches, which instead follow the syntax

```
case .. of { pat1 -> e1 ; pat2 -> e2 ; ... }
```

which can be replaced by indentation

```
case .. of
   pat1 -> e1
   pat2 -> e2
   ...
```

Also, note that partial field selectors are discouraged:

```
data A = A1 { foo :: Int } | A2
```

Above, `foo A2` type checks but crashes. On the other hand, when a field is present in all the constructors, we do not face such risk.

Comment: Perhaps you should mention explicitly that Haskell and ML each use `|` in the general sense of marking "cases", but Haskell uses it for boolean guards while ML uses it (among other things) for pattern matching. It also bears mentioning that non-total field selectors are generally discouraged (aside from non-exported ones used to make prisms).

Comment: @dfeuer Out of curiosity then, what might be the more idiomatic way to implement the `PRQuadtree` type I have? White, Black, and Grey nodes are all types of `PRQuadtree` but have different behavior for insert, delete, etc. as well as different associated data. In Java I've implemented this behavior with a `PRQuadtree` interface and White, Black, and Grey node concrete classes. 


Since all the internal data is private (and only needed in that node) it never mattered that their implementation was different.

Comment: @KyleRush, one option is to break up a sum of products into multiple types, so each product gets its own record type.

Answer (score 3):

You can also write:

```
getRegion x 
    | BlackNode y <- x -> ....
    | Greynode{}  <- x -> ....
```

but it is quite unidiomatic in this simple case.

However, in more complex programs, this pattern matching in guards can be very useful. You use multiple equations or case to distinguish the general cases, like shown by @chi. But then, you can detect special cases, like in the following made up example:

```
getRegion x = case x of
    BlackNode{region} 
        | [(0,_)] <- filter (inRegion region) interestingPoints
            -> -- region encloses exactly 1 interesting point on x axis
               ....
        | otherwise = ....
        where
           interestingPoints = .....
           inRegion :: Region -> Point -> Bool
    GreyNode{} -> ....
```